# can not find and count text with hypen in the name using awk

Tags: awk

Using the below `awk` I seem to be returning the incorrect count. Basically the ids (`input`) with a `-` in the name are not found though they are in the `file` which is searched. I am not sure what is not right in the command.  Thank you :).

**input**

```
SEPT12
SEPT5-GP1BB
SEPT9
HLA-DRB1
HLA-DRB5
```

**file**

```
chr16 4837470 4837656 SEPT12
chr16 4837536 4837656 SEPT12
chr22 19711038 19711157 SEPT5-GP1BB
chr22 19711038 19711157 SEPT5-GP1BB
chr22 19711366 19711997 SEPT5-GP1BB
chr22 19711367 19711997 SEPT5-GP1BB
chr22 19711367 19711997 SEPT5-GP1BB
chr17 75398130 75398795 SEPT9
chr17 75471590 75471995 SEPT9
chr17 75478215 75478427 SEPT9
chr6 32487136 32487438 HLA-DRB1
chr6 32489671 32489961 HLA-DRB1
chr6 32551875 32552165 HLA-DRB5
```

**current output**

```
2 ids found
SEPT5-GP1BB missing
HLA-DRB1 missing
HLA-DRB5 missing
```

**desired output**

```
 5 ids found
```

**awk** (missing.awk)

```
BEGIN { FS="[[:space:]]+|-" }
NR == FNR { seen[$0]; next }
$4 in seen { found[$4]; delete seen[$4] }
END { print length(found) " ids found"
  for (i in seen) print i " missing" }

awk -f missing.awk input file > out
```

Comment: The problem is that you're including the `-` in your field separator `FS`. So while `seen` includes `SEPT5-GP1BB` from the first file (because there you used `$0`, which includes the separators), `$4` in the second file is simply `SEPT5`.  If you set `FS="[[:space:]]+` you should be fine --- but then that's the default anyway, so you don't need to set `FS` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { lookup[$0]++; next }
    ($4 in lookup) { seen[$4]++ } 
    END {
      print length(seen)" ids found"; 
      for (id in seen) delete lookup[id]; 
      for (id in lookup) print id " is missing"
}' input file
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly does your output represent? Are you counting the number of elements in input that were found in file, regardless of how many times they were found?

If so, I think your code is fine as long as you don't (mis)set `FS`. It seems to work for me when I comment that line out.

Comment: Thank you all for your help and explanations :).